# Why we need multiple working process?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Yesterday, my customer played with the IIS settings and he changed the number of Working Process to 2 which made my Web Application ran very weird, the Session State sometimes was lost, sometimes was recovered and took me a day to find out what happened. So, the question is Multiple Working Process is useful in what situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful for scaling a web app vertically. Especially poorly designed ones that do too much work in the web processes or one where processes crash frequently so you always have a hot one. It isn't an option that should be exercised lightly as you have found out, but it is good to have when you need it.

The reason your user sessions started to fail was because you are using the default in-process session state module. This is fairly easy to fix as well -- just run the session state out of process using either the session state service or a database. Note that some behavior of the session state changes when you do this as well, so you will need to test carefully that you don't break something else.